# Regexp to replace repeating string

Tags: regex

I have a pipe delimited file and want to replace all the occurrences of |N.D.| with | | .

I did this:

```
$line =~ s/\|N.D.\|/\| \|/g;
```

but if the line has repeating N.D. like this:

```
12354|this is test|N.D|N.D|some more text|
```

it will only replace one. How do I fix it to replace all?

Comment: If it repeats, do you want to replace all with just a single pipe?  In that case, just replace `/N\.D\|/g, ''` - that leaves the first pipe and deletes the rest

Comment: @sideroxylon has the problem that it will also substitute `bar|somethingLeadingN.D|Foo` by `bar|somethingLeadingFoo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you use a simple positive lookahead for this:

`\|N\.D(?=\|)` and substitute it with `|`

```
$line =~ s/\|N\.D(?=\|)/\| /g;
```

That way the trailing `|` is not included in the match and the next match will be able to start there.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! You actually noticed another bug I had where I didn't escape the dots.